# Android Library Project Dependencies and NoClassDefFound

Tags: android, maven, gradle

EDIT: This project demos the behavior:

https://github.com/NathanielWaggoner/AndroidExamples/tree/master/packing

There is a read me that explains the first time you build it.

I have a set of projects built using Gradle and AndroidStudio.  We'll call them `Lib1, SDK and APP`.  `Lib1` and `SDK` are deployed to a private Sonotype repo that I maintain.

`App` depends on `SDK` -  App is a normal android project

`SDK` depends on `Lib1` - SDK is an Android Library Project repackaged as a Jar

`Lib1` depends on some Android Stuff. - `Lib1` is a normal android library project, packaged as an aar.

When I run `gradle dependencies` In each project i see some things i don't expect.

In `Lib1` I see all appropriate dependencies, just as I would expect (including dependencies of dependencies)

In `SDK` I see all relevant dependencies and their trees except for that of Lib1.  In the case of lib1 the only thing I see is lib1, not any of its dependencies.

In `APP` i see something very simlar to the `SDK` dependencies - I see all dependencies are their trees, except for `SDK`.  In the case of `SDK` I only see the `SDK`.  I don't see Lib1 listed as a dependency (or any of the other dependencies of `SDK`).

Everything builds fine - that is i can compile and deploy `Lib1`, and compile and deploy `SDK`. I can compile the `APP` - however when it uses `SDK` code which references `Lib1` I get noClassDefFound on the `Lib1` classes.

Checking the output jars none of the library classes are included in the Jars created during the build phases of `SDK` or `Lib1`, and the poms created don't reference any dependencies (from installArchives/uploadArchives tasks).

How do I work around this?  I don't want consumers of the `SDK` to have to directly compile in the Lib1 in order for those classes to be found.

Comment: Please post the relevant sections of your `build.gradle` files, particularly the `dependencies` closures where you are setting all of this up.

Comment: Ok added all three.  Had to make some edits to make them internet safe, hopefully their still understandable.

Comment: If I were in your shoes, I'd create a second set of projects that **solely** exist to try to reproduce the dependency network that you are trying to set up between the three projects. I have no idea if all the extra stuff in your `build.gradle` files are perhaps interfering with matters. Hence, I would get rid of the extra stuff in a parallel set of projects, to see if I can work out the right stuff for the dependencies, *then* try to apply that to the full projects that have all your extra configuration options.

Comment: Yea thats what I'm thinking i'm going to have to do.  That SDK build file is legacy and I'm not really sure what its doing either.

Comment: https://github.com/NathanielWaggoner/AndroidExamples/tree/master/packing this project is a minimum case for how to reproduce this behavior.  There's a read me with some stuff that might be interesting.  Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: I'd say it has to do with the Maven plugin. Your `lib2` POM does not have a dependency on `lib1`. Also note that to build your project, rather than the comment-out stuff (which didn't really work when I tried it, as `app` couldn't find classes), I went into `library1` and ran **`gradle build installArchives`**, then went into `library2` and ran **`gradle build installArchives`**, rather than running those from the top level.

Comment: Thanks, yea I just found this:

http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/using_the_maven_publish_plugin_no_dependencies_in_pom_xml

Which sounds eerily similar to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic:

http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/using_the_maven_publish_plugin_no_dependencies_in_pom_xml

shows some extremely similar behavior to what it turns out was happening to me - my poms were being generated without their dependency information being included.

For now i've got this work around in my installArchives.`

```
task installArchives(type: Upload) {
        repositories.mavenInstaller {
            configuration = configurations.archives
            //configuration = configurations.default
            pom.version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
            pom.artifactId = "lib2"
            pom.groupId = "waggoner.android.examples"
            pom.withXml {
                def node = asNode().appendNode('dependencies').appendNode('dependency')
                node.appendNode('groupId','waggoner.android.examples')
                node.appendNode('artifactId','lib1')
                node.appendNode('version','0.0.1-SNAPSHOT')
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As a note - this appears to be an issue with the maven plugin and the android plugin.  The poms are generated correctly (I believe) if you use the java plugin instead of android.